# Со вступлением или с вступлением, с или со?

Tags: предлоги

Со вступлением Положения о новой форме для сотрудников будут приниматься меры по выполнению этих правил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предлог **СО**, так как в противном случае устанавливается ряд труднопроизносимых согласных звуков [сфст].

Другое дело, что само предложение построено неверно. Слово "вступление" в заданном смысле предполагает наличие при нём управляемого слова, например: вступление в силу.

**Вариант:**

***Со вступлением в силу "Положения о новой форме для сотрудников" будут приниматься меры по выполнению изложенных в документе правил.***